# OrientDB: Cannot execute the request because an asynchronous operation is in progress

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

When I'm querying my OrientDb (2.2.18) more than once  in this way:

```
def orientService =  new OrientGraphFactory(url, username, password).setupPool(1, 50)

orientService.getNoTx().command(new OCommandSQL(query)).execute().toList()
```

I have this:

```
Cannot execute the request because an asynchronous operation is in progress. Please use a different connection
DB name="MyDB"
```

How can I avoid it? Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using? 2.2.18 is quite old, have you already tried with 2.2.29?

Comment: I'm using Groovy. There is an issue about this? Is necessary to upgrade on 2.2.29? (I'm waiting for v3 to migrate my app)

Comment: We fixed many issues since 2.2.18, if you can try on last version (now 2.2.30) and the problem persists, please open a new issue on github.

Comment: @Lvca, there is a best practice to make concurrent and asynchronous queries on OrientDB?